# How can I manage the state of ListView using Hive after kill task?

Tags: flutter, flutter-listview, flutter-hive

I am trying to develop a bookmark app which you can add and delete items. I am using Hive to manage state of the items on ListView, but it doesn't work as I expected. My expectation is that items which are added on ListView are still on the view after kill task. Also, another expectation is that if I delete the default items (Google and Apple) and kill task, the items are deleted. How can I implement these using Hive?

```
late Box box;
const bookmarkBox = 'bookmark_box';

Future<void> main() async {

  await Hive.initFlutter();

  box = await Hive.openBox(bookmarkBox);
  runApp(const BookmarkApp());
}

class BookmarkApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const BookmarkApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Bookmark App',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.white),
        useMaterial3: false,
      ),
      home:  BookmarkListPage(text: '', url: '',),
    );
  }
}

class BookmarkListPage extends StatefulWidget {
  BookmarkListPage({super.key, title, required this.text, required this.url});

  String text;
  String url;

  final String title = 'Bookmark';

  @override
  State<BookmarkListPage> createState() => _BookmarkListPageState();
}

class _BookmarkListPageState extends State<BookmarkListPage> {

// these are default value but you are able to delete them
  List<String> bookmarkList = ['Google', 'Apple'];
  List<String> bookmarkUrl = [
    'https://www.google.com/',
    'https://www.apple.com/jp/',
  ];

  _launchUrl(int index) async {
    var url = Uri.parse(bookmarkUrl[index]);
    if (await canLaunchUrl(url)) {
      await launchUrl(url);
    } else {
      throw "Could not open $url";
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    var box = Hive.box(bookmarkBox);

    box.get('BookmarkTitle', defaultValue: 'Not Title');
    box.get('BookmarkUrl', defaultValue: 'No URL');

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        title: Text(
          widget.title,
          style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.black),
        ),
        bottom: PreferredSize(
          child: Container(
            height: 1,
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
          preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(1),
        ),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: bookmarkList.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          // you can swipe to delete items
          return Dismissible(
            background: Container(
              color: Colors.red,
              child: Icon(
                Icons.delete,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
            onDismissed: (direction) {
              setState(() {
                bookmarkList.removeAt(index);
              });
            },
            key: UniqueKey(),
            child: Card(
              child: ListTile(
                title: Text(
                  bookmarkList[index],
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontSize: 20,
                  ),
                ),
                subtitle: Text(bookmarkUrl[index]),
                onTap:() => _launchUrl(index),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),

     
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        shape: const CircleBorder(),
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
        onPressed: () async {
          final (newBookmarkTitle, newBookmarkUrl) = await showDialog(
              context: context,
              builder: (_) {
                return BookmarkDialog();
              });

          setState(() {
            bookmarkList.add(newBookmarkTitle);
            bookmarkUrl.add(newBookmarkUrl);
            box.put('BookmarkTitle', bookmarkList);
            box.put('BookmarkUrl', bookmarkUrl);
          });

        },
        child: const Icon(
          Icons.add,
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from what I'm seeing your not using the box correctly

`bookmarkList` and `bookmarkUrl` should be always be the same as the contents of the box. meaning each something happens to those lists it should reflect on the box

so:

1. when instantiating them:

   ```
   List<dynamic> bookmarkList = box.get('BookmarkTitle', defaultValue: ['Google', 'Apple']);
   List<dynamic> bookmarkUrl = box.get('BookmarkUrl', defaultValue: ['https://www.google.com/', 'https://www.apple.com/jp/']);
   ```
2. when deleting an item:

   ```
       onDismissed: (direction) {
          setState(() {
            bookmarkList.removeAt(index);
            bookmarkUrl.removeAt(index);
            box.put('BookmarkTitle', bookmarkList);
            box.put('BookmarkUrl', bookmarkUrl);
          });
        },
   ```
3. when adding a new item, which you did correctly:

   ```
      setState(() {
        bookmarkList.add(newBookmarkTitle);
        bookmarkUrl.add(newBookmarkUrl);
        box.put('BookmarkTitle', bookmarkList);
        box.put('BookmarkUrl', bookmarkUrl);
      });
   ```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I solved it. Thank you so much again